# setting a variable in javascript to be used in another form

Tags: javascript

I have form with a Grid (telerik), i think the technology behind it doesnt matter. I let user click on a row in the grid. During the click I extract a value from the Grid with Javascript, like so:

```
function RadDrillDoubleClick(sender, eventArgs) {
   var Code = eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("Status");

   if (Code == "In Progress" || Code == "")
      {
         location.href = "Main1.aspx?mode=edit&DID=" + eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("D_ID");
       }
    else  {
         location.href = "Main1.aspx?mode=view&DID=" + eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("D_ID");
           }
     }
```

After user has clicked the grid, I call this JS function and send them to correct .aspx page with either VIEW or EDIT mode dependent directly on the Code.

What I'm trying to do is once I get to the Main1.aspx page, I want to be able to continue to hold the CODE value, because when users performs a certain action, I'll need to call a javascript function and use the actual CODE to determine what the user will be able to do.....

```
var Code = eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("Status");
```

is there any way I can somehow create like a GLOBAL Variable called

```
CodeValue
```

that I can pass around to another form without doing it in the URL?

Comment: Put `Code` in a cookie, localStorage, or sessionStorage. That's how you can send variables between different pages.

Comment: Take a look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: You might want to pass it as an URL parameter, just like you do with `D_ID`. Make sure to properly escape it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the browser navigates to a page, all current JavaScript is unloaded from the browser. This means any functions/variables, etc. will not be accessible on the new page unless you've persisted the value in some way.

Common ways of persisting the value include:

1. Add it to the query string of the URL the user is navigating to
2. Save the value to a cookie
3. Save the value to local/session storage

For your scenario, #1 is probably your best bet (keep in mind the user can have multiple browsers/tabs open to your site).

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the value from `URL` is like this: on the page `Main1.aspx`, you add to your `JavaScript` a `function` that will run after page loads and that will get what it needs from the current `URL`

```
var globalValue; // variable that will receive the value from URL

window.onload = function() {
  var thisURL = window.location.href;
  globalValue = url.split("?").pop();

  // this will store in globalValue everything that comes after the last "?"
  // example: if the url is www.site.com/text?value, it will store string "value" to globalValue
};
```